# Как парсить страницы которые подгружаются с помощью js на php

Tags: php, node.js, puppeteer

Знаю что это можно легко делать на nodejs, там есть puppeteer. Если что-то такое для php, или каким другим способом это можно делать?

Comment: https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer ?

Comment: Спасибо, большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

github.com/nesk/puphpeteer - для php